# How to add QDockWidgets as tab?

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I'm trying to create a Qt application with tabified QDockWidgets.

[image: example tabified docks]

I know there is a `QMainWindow::tabifyDockWidget` to tabify QDockWidgets but since I'm doing everything related to UI in Qt Designer, I was wondering if there is some option in the designer to do so without adding extra code.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without code